# Why am I getting one empty array item in every other array like a pattern? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, polygon, is-empty

**UPDATE AT THE BOTTOM OF THE POST!**

---

### **This is the first part of a program that will eventually make SVG star polygons.**

**Only star polygons that can be made in one go, I.e. like a Pentagram,** NOT like a Hexagram that can only be made with at least 2 shapes I.e. 2 inverted and overlapping triangles.

**I'm almost finished with this. Everything seems to be working well and I'm getting the out put I want except there's an empty array item in every other array produced for some reason.**

### In this part

I'm printing to the console (for testing) an object with items named with numbers that represent the number of points / sides of a regular polygon. **Within each item is an array with the lower half of all the non factoring numbers of that item (number)** I.e. an array of numbers that when the number (item name) is divided by them, it will return a fraction.

***E.g. Object***

- *starPolygons{**'5':** 2, **'7':** 3, 2, **'8':** 3, **'9':** 4, 2, …}*
- *(Representation of: Pentagon: Heptagon: Octagon: Nonagon: …)*

---

### What "qty_test" functions does

The **points** variable (= 8 for example) is sent to a function (**qty_test**) which is used to find the number of divisors I need to test and inside it is divided by 2. If the result is a fraction, it will return the result rounded back, and if its even, it will return the result - 1.

```
//8 has more divisors to cycle through -so its a better example!
//In the real program, it will be 5.
let points = 8;
let starPolygons = {};
```

***E.g. qty_test***

1. *point (=8) ()=> n /= 2 (=4)*
2. *if n - n(rounded-back) = 0?*
3. *true returns (n -1) and false returns n(rounded-back)*

```
function qty_test(n) {

    n /= 2;

    let divisorQTY = n - Math.floor(n) !== 0;


    return divisorQTY ? Math.floor(n) : (n - 1);
};
```

---

### What divisor_test functions does

This function uses the number returned from the previous function (**n**) to set a for loop that tests every cycle if **n** is not a factor of the value of the **points** variable. I.e. **points** divided by **n** returns a fraction and if it returns true, meaning a fraction was produced **n**`s value is indexed in an array and decreaces by 1 (**--n**).

***E.g. divisor_test***

- *n(=8) / **2** = 4 << **2** will be ignored.*
- *n(=8) / **3** = 2.666... << **3** will be collected*

```
function divisor_test(n) {

    let nonFactors = [];

    n = qty_test(n);

    for (let index = 0; index <= n; index++) {

        let quotient = (points / n) - Math.floor(points / n) !== 0;
        quotient ? nonFactors[index] = n-- : --n;

    };
    return nonFactors;
};
```

---

**The program cycles through 5 - 360 and indexes an object with numbers (5-360) and array list of their lower half non factor numbers.**

```
while (points <= 360) {

    nonFactors = divisor_test(points);

    let testArray = nonFactors.length;

    if (testArray) starPolygons[String(points)] = nonFactors;

    points++;
};
console.log(starPolygons);
```

**AS YOU  CAN SEE IN THIS IMAGE. THE PATTERN OF EMPTY ARRAY INDEXES / ITEMS**

[image]

---

**UPDATE: I NOTICED THE PATTERN OF ARRAYS WITH THE EMPTY SLOTS HAS AN INTERESTING QUALITY TO IT.** This is so cool and so confusing as to what causes this...
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the Iteration you are forcing the array to add an empty item.
So, the empty object appears when the array has only two items in it and you are trying to nonFactors[3] = n--;
and thats what causes the issue.

So a more simplified version of the for loop with the solution will be

```
for (let index = 0; index <= n; index++) {

    let quotient = (points / n) - Math.floor(points / n) !== 0;
    
    if(quotient){
        if(index > nonFactors.length){
            nonFactors[index - 1] = n--    
        }else{
            nonFactors[index] = n--    
        }
        
    }else{
        n = n -1;
        
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

### I solved my problem

**There's an answer here that already explains what causes the problem and also gives a working solution by Nadav Hury (upvote his answer. I bet his answer generally works better in more situations)! So I will just post my own version of a solution.**

```
    for (let index = 0; n >= 2; index++) {

        let quotient = (points / n) - Math.floor(points / n) !== 0;
        if (quotient) nonFactors[index] = n--;
        else --n, --index;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is that in the line with checking the quotient

`quotient ? nonFactors[index] = n-- : --n;`

you added setting the value only for the case when it is present that is equal to true but you didn't add to the case when it is false correct solution is:

`quotient ? nonFactors[index] = n-- : nonFactors[index] = --n;`.

Comment: Your solution returns more unwanted values. The problem is trickier than you think, because some solutions return an infinite loop...

I tried "splicing" the index of the array if "false", but it doesn't change anything.

I think anyone who wants to try and solve this problem needs to run the code themselves.

Because, if it was simple as your solution than why is there only one empty index for only some of the arrays and why not for every factor (numbers I ignore)?